# Where do I find the consumer_key for my app on Yammer?

Tags: api, yammer

I want to use the impersonator endpoint for yammer but I can't figure out where to find the consumer key for my app.

on the documentation I found this

> Generates (if necessary) and returns a list of authorized OAuth 2.0 access following parameters passed in the query string:
>
> user_id – string. The user_id of the user on behalf of whom you are generating the access tokens.
>
> consumer_key – string. The app’s consumer key which is available in the app that you registered.
>
> Verified Admins may use the user_id and consumer_key parameters to generate tokens on behalf of other users. Non-Admins are not able to use these parameters, only getting back oauth tokens for networks that they are a part of.
>
> Source: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/impersonation

Problem is that I just have client ID, secret and redirect under the "keys and tokens" section of my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Client ID" is used as the OAuth consumer key. This can be found for your application at https://www.yammer.com/client_applications.

Comment: I got through 3 people from their support team on the phone before getting this answer. It is correct but, not in their documentation.